# How can I find values that are the same within a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, filter

Currently I have a code that creates a dictionary with a key and a list as its value:

```
e.g. dct = {A: [hello, only], B: [hello, that], C: [hello, same]}
```

I'd like to compare the different values of the dictionary and identify values that are shared by all keys. In this example, "hello" is shared by all three keys. Still pretty new to python! Thank you so much!

Comment: your keys and list element has to be enclosed in quote for them to be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.intersection(*[set(list) for list in dct.values()])
```

will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should create dictionary properly.
Try this code.

```
dct = {'A':['hello', 'only'], 'B':['hello', 'that'], 'C':['hello', 'same']}
s=set.intersection(*[set(list) for list in dct.values()])
print(s)
```

output.

```
{'hello'}
```